# implement if statement inside subtitle in ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

is there any way i can implement an if statement inside a subtitle in ListTile? i can put it directly inside a widget but not in title/subtitle

```html
ListTile(
  title: Text("Location"),
  subtitle: if (_currentPosition != null) Text(_currentAddress),
  trailing: IconButton(...),
),
```

this gives an error "Expected an identifier. dart(missing_identifier)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
subtitle: _currentPosition == null?
        Text('No position found') //code if above statement is true
        :Text(_currentAddress), //code if above statement is false
```

Comment: It works!! but whenever i go back to homepage and return to location page the text restart to "No position found"

Comment: I would have to see more of your code, it sounds like your _currentPosition is null before it loads in, is it async? if it is async you need to call it in your initState()

Comment: [here](https://codeshare.io/5DyzZl) is my code. sorry for being afk'd

Comment: Yeah, there are a couple ways you could do this. You could make a variable called 'firstTimeLoaded' and set it equal to 0, and if it is equal to 0, then you run _getCurrentLocation and add 1 to firstTimeLoaded. Or you could have a tracker in homePage that holds a location, and when you pop to homePage you pass the location back with it, and then when you go back into settingsPage you could pass the location along with it

Comment: Is it also possible to hide the subtitle at all if null ?